# .Net Core SignalR cannot add or use in startup

Tags: c#, .net-core, signalr

Ive recently come back to an old .Net Core application which was using SignalR.

I think at the time the only SignalR NuGet package available for .Net Core applications was a preview. And it worked.

Im now on a new machine and dont know what the preview feed was for this package so ive uninstalled it and installed this:

```
> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core -Version 2.4.1
```

Everything seems fine with a few namespace changes apart from these two errors in the Startup.cs file.

> Error CS1061  'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for
>   'AddSignalR' and no accessible extension method 'AddSignalR' accepting
>   a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Error CS1061  'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for
>   'UseSignalR' and no accessible extension method 'UseSignalR' accepting
>   a first argument of type 'IApplicationBuilder' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I've looked around and there isn't much available for me, other than someone suggesting you need to install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Http` which I cant find. Someone else suggested you need to install this:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client -Version 1.1.0
```

Which I've tried, but the errors remain, how do I get these to go away?

[image]

Comment: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR` is part of ASP.NET Core since 2.1. Which version are you targeting?

Comment: The project was targeting 2.0 but I've changed it to 2.2 now

Comment: The AddSignalR extension method resides in the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection namespace. Are you using this namespace?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR` is part of ASP.NET Core since 2.1.

So if you set the target version to NET Core 2.1 or higher under Project->Properties->Target framework in Visual Studio, you should be able to call `services.AddSignalR()` in your `ConfigureServices` method.

Comment: Yeah I should be able to, but I can't. I get the error message in question.

Comment: Did you rebuild after changing the target version?

Comment: Yeah, cleaned, rebuild, close and re-opened.

Comment: What if you create a new project that targets .NET Core 2.1 from the start. Do you have `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;` at the top?

Comment: I created a brand new solution with a project targeting .Net Core 2.1. The references to UseSignalR and AddSignalR worked fine. If I target my application (which was manually upgraded to .Net Core 2 around 12 months ago, the complication errors are still there. So it feels like its something to do with the fact that this project was .Net Core 1.0 to begin with.

Comment: @JsonStatham: Then your upgrade has obviously failed. Does it build if you remove the call to `AddSignalR()`?

Comment: I arrived here because I am putting together a brand new .net 5 application.  The error remains. Farman's answer solved it for me.

Comment: If you are unable to AddSignalR() you need to add this to your project file:

<ItemGroup>
<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>

(Note that that tag is FrameworkReference not ProjectReference or PackageReference)

Answer (score 61):

I solved the issue by replacing the code from

```
app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<NotifyHub>("notify"); 
        });
```

to

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapHub<NotifyHub>("/notify");
        });
```

I am using Dot net 5.0

Comment: Tank you! This did the trick for me as well!

Comment: Thank you. Yes. this is a working solution if you are using .net 5

Comment: Worth mentioning that this should be in Program.cs not Startup.cs in .NET5

Answer (score 18):

As already pointed out by @Farman, the solution is to use `.UseEndpoints()`. As documented by MSFT this is the recommended approach by replacing `.UseSignalR()`,

Recomended approach:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapHub<SomeHub>("/path");
});
```

The `.UseSignalR()` became obosolete from .NET Core version 3.0 and it was recomended to move to `.UseEndpoints()` starting .NET Core version 3.1.

More information can be found [AspNet Core Compatability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnetcore)

Answer (score 4):

**Dot net 5.0**

Add package first:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core --version 2.4.1
```

In, public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)

```
services.AddSignalR();
```

In, public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapHub<NotifyHub>("/notify");
        });
```

Comment: That package is for regular .Net framework. The question specifies Net Core.

Answer (score 1):

I found a reference to an old Mvc nuget in a project dependency that caused the rest of the projects to load old .net core packages even when every project has a .net6.0 configuration (caused by a wrong .net update).
The solution to be able to add the *Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core* reference without adding any package (*signalR is included in netcore*) was to remove the Mvc nuget reference and include the next reference in the csproj.

```
<ItemGroup>
   <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```